# Target (Instance on Elastic Beanstalk) is getting removed from AWS target group after deployment or auto-scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-auto-scaling

**Background:**

I have an ALB & Elastic Beanstalk running. I have configured my ALB as a Shared Load Balancer in my Elastic Beanstalk. Also, I have registered the instance of my Elastic Beanstalk as a target in Target Group on same ALB.

**Problem:**

After deployment or due to auto-scaling, instance gets added/removed from Elastic Beanstalk and this is causing deregistering of target from my target group.

**Query**

How can we prevent this ?

Or do we have any solution so that newly added instance of EB gets automatically registered to my Target Group of same ALB ?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind autoscaling group of elastic beanstalk environment to your target group which is associated to your loadbalancer.

1. Go to EC2 > Auto Scaling groups
2. In detail of Auto Scaling group there is Load balancing section > click on Edit
3. There you can select your target group